# Inspect http request in angularJS 1.7.0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I need to see if the request starts from an internal or external network.

How can I intercept the http in angular 1.7 request and find the information I'm looking for?

Comment: You can intercept requests which are originating only from your browser... You can use tools like fiddler, postman. Or on your browser press F12 and check network tab.

Comment: Have you read [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. AngularJS originates HTTP requests. It does not receive requests that start elsewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you're just trying to see the request... why not check the developer tools?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire yes, I want to see the request, but I would like to memorize a flag on the db that informs me of the origin of the request.
My backend is written in python